# Why are patterns in Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns double quoted?

Tags: f#, quotations

The active pattern

```
Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns.``|AddressSet|_|``
```

has its last element double quoted. Why is it double quoted? What is the use of those quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically anything surrounded by double backticks (``` ``...`` ```) is just an identifier that otherwise would not be a valid identifier in the language.

For example, if you want to use a language keyword as a function name (not recommended!) you could escape it in this way. If you didn't use the ``` `` ``` delimiters, this would be a syntax error:

```
let ``let`` x = printfn "%i" x

``let`` 5
``let`` 8
```

So in your case, that statement must be appearing in a context where the active pattern syntax is not recognized as being valid. What is the context in which you see it written this way?

Comment: There is no context for now. I just open a new file, type **Patterns.** and press **tab** and the snippet in the above question appears. The weird thing is that I couldn't find any example of this. Can you point me to somewhere that I can start reading?

Comment: The [Symbol and Operator Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/) gives a brief explanation of all symbols in the language, but in this case does not provide any further information...